# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte. What should I do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, byte, decoding

It doesn't decode it properly. In fact, it says what's on the title. What does it mean? What should I do?

`im1_bytes = client_socket.recv(int_size)
im1_str = im1_bytes.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: What's `client_socket` from?

Comment: Why do you try to decode an _image_ as utf-8?

Comment: @n1c9 What do you mean? I defined it at the top of the page and everything. It get's stuff from server_socket.

Comment: @tkausl Actually it's not an "image", I made a mistake... It's bytes... afterwards I'll hopefully remake them an image. Excuse me, it's my first question. Anyways, how should I decode that?

Comment: `It's bytes` What does that even mean? _What_ kind of data exactly is this? If its not utf-8 encoded text then you can't utf-8 decode it.

Comment: @tkausl data = open(r'C:\Downloads\screen.jpg', "rb").read() that's on the server side. Then I send *exactly* that "data" variable to the client. It goes into im1_bytes. How should I decode that?

Comment: You don't need to decode then. Just save the bytes to a file.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you very much :)